# Supporting Multiple Screens in Android Devices?

Tags: android

I developed a sample web application and hosted that .apk build file in different Android version and on different sized devices, here I am getting problems in my design in layout such as listview not being displayed properly, bottom portion not displaying well, and the alignment not so good.

Comment: Is the question the topic? If so, please be more specific. You build your apk for different android versions? Android is backward compatible, build an apk for 1.5 means it runs on 2.2, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently came across a problem when creating my first game.  After attempting to fix the issue of different screen sizes, I also realized you need to worry about pixel density as well.  I'm not too sure what all you have being drawn to the screen but you can have those resized as needed to be the same ratio with the screen on any device.  All you might have to do is add the following code to the manifest section of the Manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"/>
```

This took care of my problem with different devices, I hope it works for you as well!

Comment: Just a note that if you have to use anyDensity = false to make your layout look correct then you may want to re-evaluate your layouts.  If you use density independent units (dp) instead of pixels along with providing sized assets for low/medium/high density devices then your layouts and assets will look optimal on all devices.  The link that Macarse provides gives details on this.  Read the description of the anyDensity parameter: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#attrs

Answer (score 2):

You can use these in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```